# jquary слайдер текста

Tags: javascript, jquery, анимация

Как сделать так чтобы каждые 5 секунд менялся текст?
Мой код

```js
setInterval(function() {
  $('.fot-kill-txt:contains("Всего убийств")').text("Всего смертей");
  $('.fot-global-txt:contains("5")').text("15");
  $('.fot-global-txt-you:contains("3")').text("16");
}, 5000);

setInterval(function() {
  $('.fot-kill-txt:contains("Всего смертей")').text("Всего убийств животных");
  $('.fot-global-txt:contains("15")').text("3");
  $('.fot-global-txt-you:contains("16")').text("5");
}, 10000);

setInterval(function() {
  $('.fot-kill-txt:contains("Всего убийств животных")').text("Всего убийств");
  $('.fot-global-txt:contains("3")').text("9");
  $('.fot-global-txt-you:contains("5")').text("2");

}, 12000);
```

```html
<div class="fot-kill-txt">Всего убийств</div>
    <div class="fot-global-left-title">Глобальный</div>
    <div class="fot-global-txt">5
    </div>
    <div class="fot-global-left-title">Вы</div>
    <div class="fot-global-txt-you">3</div>
```

Comment: если каждые 5 минут, то причем тут 12000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаю необходимые параметры занести либо в массив, либо в объект с нужными полями и уже манипулировать этими данными в функции `setInterval`.

Пример:

```js
var values = [
 ['Всего убийств', 5, 3],
 ['Всего смертей', 15, 16],
 ['Всего убийств животных', 3, 5]
];

var index = 1;
var interval = 2000; // 2 secs.

setInterval(function() {
  if (index > values.length - 1)
      index = 0;
    
  $('.fot-kill-txt').text(values[index][0]);
  $('.fot-global-txt').text(values[index][1]);
  $('.fot-global-txt-you').text(values[index][2]);
  
  index++;
}, interval);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fot-kill-txt">Всего убийств</div><br />

<div class="fot-global-left-title">Глобальный</div>
<div class="fot-global-txt">5</div><br />

<div class="fot-global-left-title">Вы</div>
<div class="fot-global-txt-you">3</div>
```

Конечно, лучше данные привязать к ключам (типа `values = {name: Всего убийств, death:3, animals: 5}`), т.к. невозможно помнить в какой ячейке массива что именно хранится и обращение, к примеру `array[1][2]` ни о чем не скажет - что там и зачем. Следует это помнить.

Comment: Спасибо огромное...

Comment: @Sauron Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).